# How to check what data/columns/tables(in MSSQL) are created when installing certain windows service

Tags: sql-server, windows, service

What is the best way to find out what is created/inserted in the database when I install certain windows service?

Comment: Export the database, install, export the database again, run a diff over the exports.

Comment: Use extended events to track the statements the service account runs?

Comment: There is no "best" way since that cannot be measured and is relative to your abilities, your tools, available resources, and your ultimate goal. Perhaps the [schema compare function in SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used.